# Using vanilla Ubuntu, a script to search and replace/uncomment a block of code?

Tags: bash, perl, ubuntu, nginx, sed

I am trying to automate the installation in Ubuntu 14.04 of a development environment, part of this requires that I uncomment a block of code for the Nginx vHost configuration:

```
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #       fastcgi_index index.php;
    #       include fastcgi_params;
    #}
```

I tried sed:

```
sed -i "s/#location ~ \.php$ {
        #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #       # NOTE: You should have \"cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;\" in php.ini
        #
        #       # With php5-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php5-fpm:
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #       fastcgi_index index.php;
        #       include fastcgi_params;
        #}/location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(\/.+)$;
          # NOTE: You should have \"cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;\" in php.ini

          # With php5-cgi alone:
          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
          # With php5-fpm:
          fastcgi_pass unix:\/var\/run\/php5-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          include fastcgi_params;
        }/g" /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx.dev;
```

But this returns:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command
```

Which I assume relates to syntax errors, I tried to escape the `/` and `"` characters but I think that this is not enough / right at all.

I found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26289/138115

Which suggested that perl might be a good solution here and as it is installed with Ubuntu I tried it:

```
perl -0777 -i.original -pe 's/#location ~ \.php$ {\n        #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(\/.+)$;\n        #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini\n        #\n        #       # With php5-cgi alone:\n        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;\n        #       # With php5-fpm:\n        #       fastcgi_pass unix:\/var\/run\/php5-fpm.sock;\n        #       fastcgi_index index.php;\n        #       include fastcgi_params;\n        #}/slocation ~ \.php$ {\n  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(\/.+)$;\n  NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini\n  With php5-cgi alone:\n  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;\n  With php5-fpm:\n  fastcgi_pass unix:\/var\/run\/php5-fpm.sock;\n  fastcgi_index index.php;\n  include fastcgi_params;\n}/igs' /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx.dev;
```

But this gives a whole host of syntax errors:

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near "(."
Unknown regexp modifier "/v" at -e line 1, within string
Unknown regexp modifier "/r" at -e line 1, within string
Unknown regexp modifier "/h" at -e line 1, within string
Unknown regexp modifier "/5" at -e line 1, within string
Not enough arguments for index at -e line 1, near "index."
syntax error at -e line 1, near "n}"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I have written quite a few scripts like this before for various environments but I have tried always to avoid replacing multiple lines of text because i've never been able to get it right. Today, i've spent 3 hours and I still have no real understanding on how to make this work out. If anyone could share some input / insight into this and how it could be accomplished then it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit 1:**

Simple escape with square brackets:

```
#!/bin/bash
#/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.sh
file=$(<default.file);
search=$(<nginx_search.txt);
replace=$(<nginx_replace.txt);
$file =~ s[$search][$replace]g;
echo "$file" > "/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.file";
# Outputs notice: ./test.sh: line 6: #: command not found
```

The `test.file` is created but it contains the original values of `default.file` without the amendment.

After testing in perl I receive:

```
syntax error at ./perl.perl line 6, near "(."
Unknown regexp modifier "/v" at ./perl.perl line 6, within string
Unknown regexp modifier "/r" at ./perl.perl line 6, within string
Unknown regexp modifier "/h" at ./perl.perl line 6, within string
Unknown regexp modifier "/5" at ./perl.perl line 6, within string
syntax error at ./perl.perl line 9, near ";
}"
Execution of ./perl.perl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

And line 6 reads:

```
#       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
```

Comment: Will the code in question be in the same place in all files, or do you need it dynamic?

Comment: @TLP The file in question might change in the future releases so it would be best to make it dynamic / not dependant on line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - you mention (and tag) `perl`. The below is from a `perl` perspective. Some of it may be applicable to conventional shell, but I can't say for sure exactly what. `perl` does support some regex things that are above and beyond the base `POSIX` spec.

The problem with patterns like that, is that you've got delimiters in your pattern. Your initial is failing because it'll be treating this slash:

```
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

As the 'split point' in the pattern. You can handle this by escaping the delimiter, but actually a better trick is - use delimiters that don't exist elsewhere. In the above, I'd suggest you can use square brackets:

```
my $str = "some fish"; 
$str =~ s[some][more]g;

print $str;
```

Although as an alternative - you can use a [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) which tests as 'true' if it's within two designated delimitors:

```
while ( <> ) {
   if ( m|\#location.*php\$ \{| .. m|^\s*#\}| ) {
       s/#//;
   }
   print ;
}
```

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


while ( <DATA> ) {
   if ( m|\#location.*php\$ \{| .. m|^\s*#\}| ) {
       #note - no g modifier, so we only do the first per line
       s/#//;
   }
   print ;
}

__DATA__
# Some stuff
we don't care about this line
#and this shouldn't be changed

#but after this point, it should be!

   #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #       fastcgi_index index.php;
    #       include fastcgi_params;
    #}


# and now we stop, and leave this bit alone. 

    more stuff; 
    here; 
    # and another comment line
```

This conditionally applies the transform if you're between two delimiters (location php and 'close squiggly brackets' in the above).

You can one-liner-ify this:

```
perl -ne 'if ( m|\#location.*php\$ \{| .. m|^\s*#\}| ) { s/#//g; } print' myfile
```

(and add `-i` if you want to edit in place).

Comment: Curly brackets are in the string, at char 22, where the error occurred

Comment: So they are.  OK, Square brackets then!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your input. I did try to accommodate for this by using \ before the / to try to escape it. Would that have escaped it or am i trying to do something that doesnt apply here? I will give the square brackets a try :-)

Comment: or range operator to  conditionally apply the pattern.

Comment: This is a wealth of information, thanks so much. I will take time to test all the variations!

Comment: Please see the edit to my question, not sure why it will not work given those details?

Comment: Probably won't work like that in `bash`. Can't say for sure though - gave up on `bash` 15 years ago and moved to `perl` ;)

Comment: So this is all perl then? Please note this at the top of the answer. That being said, I envy that kind of knowledge lol, you've made me want to learn perl even more now, thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Edited.

Comment: That one liner... After all of this it worked like a charm :-) All in all, perl > sed/bash, I learnt something new today! Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah, I don't like quoting perl one liners, because it really can get hard to read very quickly. It's essentially condensing the rest of the answer though, which hopefully clarifies what's actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

These long string replacements are always finicky, I think, and it is often best to try and avoid dealing with the content as much as possible. I came up with this, which simply captures the string, takes away the first `#` and reprints the line:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $search = q|#location ~ \.php$ {
    #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #       fastcgi_index index.php;
    #       include fastcgi_params;
    #}
|;

local $/;   # slurp the file
while (<DATA>) {
    s|(\Q$search\E)| my $x = $1; $x =~ s/^\s*#//mg; $x; |e;
    print;
}    
__DATA__
    # stuff
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #       fastcgi_index index.php;
    #       include fastcgi_params;
    #}
    #comment
```

Note the use of `\Q ... \E` to avoid the regex meta characters in the string to mess you up.

With this method, you should technically be able also to read the search strings from a file if you would want that.

Comment: Thanks! This is an interesting topic for me and I appreciate the extra answer and info. I agree that this is something to avoid and I usually bring it down to one line at a time but I can't really do that here because of the `#}` being repeated. Either way and in the end, it beats manually installing and configuring everything again in the future :-)

Comment: Okay after testing this, I get the output of the file back but the code block in question is still commented. The only addition that I have made is to load the file its self: `open(DATA, 'nginx.dev') or die "Can't read file 'filename' [$!]\n";`. Any idea why this doesn't work out for me?

Comment: @IndigoIdentity Study the strings with Data::Dumper to see if there is hidden whitespace, perhaps. Or see if you have counted wrong somewhere. `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $yourvariable;`